# SSH: Access denied

Tags: pi-3, ssh, noobs, putty

I'm trying to access my RPi 3 via Putty from a Windows 10 laptop.
When it prompts me to choose the user I type in pi.
I have tried typing in raspberry as the password, resetting the password with sudo passwd and trying with that password but nothing works.
BTW I have already placed a file named ssh in the boot partition of my Pi so that it automatically boots with ssh on.
I'm using NOOBS 2.1.0.

Comment: Have you checked if your keyboard layout match when using Putty. Try writting the password instead of loggin, does it match?

Comment: @jlandercy Yeah, It matches

Comment: Using sudo passwd changes the root password. I don't remember if root logins via SSH are off by default, but I think they are. You should not permit root logins as a security measure.

Comment: @SteveRobillard Ok, so since it changes the root password, I tried logging in with _root@IP_, but even then when writing the password it gives me the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YES!!! Finally got it to work!
I installed Raspbian Jessie this time, not NOOBS, I introduced a modified version of @leviataint 's code, changed my Pi's password, and finally managed to SSH using the Pi username.

Answer (score 0):

Is this your first time trying to SSH into the Raspberry Pi? I did this a couple of days ago, and manually changed the Pi's configuration from the GUI interface to allow for SSHing, then rebooted.

In case you haven't seen it, here's the official documentation https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/ssh/

Comment: 1st: No, this isn't the last time I use SSH with my Pi, but the last time was quite long ago. 2nd: Yes, I did all of that, nothing seems to work.

Comment: Have you tried resetting your ssh keys with ssh-keygen -R {RPi-IP-Address}?

Comment: I tried the command, but it just gives me the following error: _ssh-keygen: /home/.ssh/known_hosts: No such file or directory_ @ginginsha

Comment: That is because root is not configured for SSH, Like I said you should not login as root.

Answer (score 0):

To begin first of all you should NOT be using a the pi while connected to the internet with open ssh ports and default credentials allowed, this is madness. 
Your machine is likely already compromised in the worst case and will be after not to long in the best case.

Step 1.
Reformat the sd card and reboot the pi ideally with a screen and keyboard, or if thats not possible then i would suggest doing the following quickly.
https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/installing-images/

Step 2. 
Boot the os either ideally with no internet and begin by adding a new user

```
sudo adduser username
```

Add the new user to sudo privilages,

```
sudo visudo
```

Under root or pi add your username and permissions

```
%root      ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
username   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

Step 3.
you want to configure and allow ssh connections either from the gui menu, adding the ssh file to the sd card before boot or using

```
sudo raspi-config
```

now you want to edit the sshd config file to deny certain users and allow others

```
sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

There are many options but the bare minimum here would be

```
AllowTcpForwarding yes CHANE TO AllowTcpForwarding no
X11Forwarding yes CHANGE TO X11Forwarding no
PermitRootLogin no

DenyUsers  pi
AllowUsers username
```

You should also consider either, changing the default pi users password to something long and secure (my suggestion) or deleting the pi account entirely.
But the above should be the bare minimum to securing your raspberry pi and only allowing access to you, not everyone.

Ideally you might look at ssh keys for access instead

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll now try and see if it works. @leviataint

Comment: Hopefully that will give you a working system, there are several other options you can edit within sshd_config just read the manual. And i would suggest ssh keys which are more secure and sometimes easier then keys

Comment: I tried your commands, but now when I try to configure my pi from system settings and reboot it, the changes aren't saved. @leviataint

Comment: did you sudo raspi-config or enter settings from the menu. also you need to edit sshd_config file with sudo privilages or by changing to root with su first

Comment: Yeah, did all of that @leviataint

Comment: And BTW, in sshd_config I have no 'AllowTcpForwarding', so I just add it. Is that correct? @leviataint

Comment: Thats strange, not sure why it isnt persisting across a reset/reboot it should do. and yes you can just add options that are missing https://linux.die.net/man/5/sshd_config is a manual for most options.

Comment: Ok, I finally managed to get permission by changing root password and logging in as root, I connected to the internet the Pi, checked the IP, wrote it in putty and... ACCESS DENIED... Nothing seems to work... @leviataint

Comment: what cmd are you putting into putty can you type it in here?

Comment: I am typing 'username'@IP @leviataint

Comment: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/ssh/ and the windows option for client just to make sure you are doing it correctly. make sure your connection type is ssh and and it should work